# doClick() not disposing frame

Tags: java, button, timer, actionlistener

I have a button with an action listener that disposes than reopens a frame. If I physically click the button it works as expected, the frame closes and the same one opens again.

I also have this action linked up with a doClick() in a timer. When the action occurs it opens a new frame without disposing of the other one. The timer works perfectly by itself.

What is the reason for this and how can I fix it? Is it a problem with the timer or calling it through the doClick?

I am relatively new to all this so this may be a simple question. Thanks

Button code:

```
frmStart s = new frmStart();
        s.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
```

doClick code (change is boolean):

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(change) {
            btnReload.doClick();
            }

        }
    }, 400);
```

Comment: Do you ever call `t.start();`?

Comment: I am using util.Timer. Doesn't that mean I don't need one. The timer works properly. It is the button action that doesn't.

Comment: Just a hunch, but when dealing with Swing objects, it tends to be better if you use the `javax.swing.Timer`  Try switching over to that and then call `t.start()` after it's functionality is defined

Answer (score 0):

With what you have provided, my best guess is to have you switch you `Timer` import from `util.Timer` to `javax.swing.Timer`

Then you would instantiate it like so:

```
Timer t = new Timer(400, (e)->{
    if(change)
        btnReload.doClick();
});
```

Then start it

```
t.start();
```

It isn't a good idea, and sometimes won't even work, to interact with swing objects outside the Swing Thread.  When using `javax.swing.Timer` it runs the defined functionality within the Swing Thread

Answer (score 0):

Dispose does not kill the frame. Quote:

> Releases all of the native screen resources used by this Window, its
>   subcomponents, and all of its owned children. That is, the resources
>   for these Components will be destroyed, any memory they consume will
>   be returned to the OS, and they will be marked as undisplayable.

The frame itself is alive until the GC kicks in. And the GC does nothing because the timer is still active. So you should dispose the frame and then cancel the timer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I have changed the button action to:                                                          
        frmStart s = new frmStart();
        s.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
        
        t.cancel();                                                                                        
        But the original jframe is still staying open.